# How to invoke the onclick / button pressed effect through document.getElementById("BtnID").click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a on screen keyboard.
I have already added buttons and bound those buttons with keyboard keys. Therefore user can click on a button on the page to type or use actual physical keyboard.
 JavaScript :

```
 document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        switch (e.which || e.keyCode) {
            case 65: document.getElementById("A").click();  break;
            case 83: document.getElementById("S").click();  break;
            case 68: document.getElementById("D").click();  break;
        }
 }
```

HTML :

```
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Print('A')" id="A">A</button>
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Print('S')" id="S">S</button>
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Print('D')" id="D">D</button>
```

Everything is working fine, The problem is when i type using physical keyboard the keypress effect is not displayed. The document.getElementById("something").click() doesn't seem to play the keypress effect. The button on screen remains static. And if i press the button using mouse the button press effect works perfectly.
Look at the below images :

[When the button 'S' is clicked using mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvLb9.jpg)

[When i press the key 'S' on my physical keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G1A8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would workaround with css styling.

```js
Print = function(button){
 button.className = 'button active';
 setTimeout( function(){ button.className = 'button'; }, 500 );
 
 console.log(button.innerHTML);
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = (e.which || e.keyCode),
  pressed = {65:'A', 83:'S', 68:'D'};
    
  if( typeof pressed[ key ] === 'undefined' )
    return;
    
  document.getElementById(pressed[ key ]).click();
 }
```

```css
.button.active {
 background:#333;
 color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Print(this)" id="A">A</button>
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Print(this)" id="S">S</button>
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Print(this)" id="D">D</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This worked fine. But now I have changed my css a bit. Now i have `.button {...}`  ,  ` .button:after {..}`  and  `.button:active:after {...}`, How can i adapt my code to play effect when pressing keyboard keys?  please see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate2)

Comment: Avoid using pseudo-class ':active'.. Always use a real css-class ( f.E: '.button.active:after ) and change the button-class on every event you want. (Keypress, click, etc.)
Do you know, what i mean?

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.keypress()` from the jQuery API:
https://api.jquery.com/keypress/